# add_rewrite_rule - Additional subpages for author pages

Tags: rewrite-rules

I want to add additonal sub pages to the author pages in WordPress. I have the following URL:

```
http://mylocalsite.site/author/USER_NAME/
```

But I also want to add URL's like this:

```
http://mylocalsite.site/author/USER_NAME/pinboard
http://mylocalsite.site/author/USER_NAME/teams
```

I've already done this to add a tag called author_view:

```
add_action('init', function( $vars ) {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%author_view%', '([^&]+)');
}, 10, 1);
```

Which works great when going to this URL:

```
http://mylocalsite.site/?author=1&author_view=pinboard
```

And then I can just retrieve the author_view with get_query_var() and do whatever I want with it.

However, I'm a bit stuck in how to get the same page with pretty permalinks and a rewrite rule. This is my rewrite rule and template_redirect:

```
add_action('init', function( $vars ) {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%author_view%', '([^&]+)');

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $author_base = $wp_rewrite->author_base;

    add_rewrite_rule(
        $author_base . '/([^/]*)/([^/]*)',
        'index.php?author=$matches[1]&author_view=$matches[2]', 
        'top'
    );
    
}, 10, 1);

add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    $author_view = get_query_var( 'author_view', false );
    if($author_view) :
        include( get_template_directory() . "/author.php" );
        exit();
    endif;
} );
```

But then I get a bunch of errors since the queried object isn't the author object. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which works great when going to this URL:
>
> `http://mylocalsite.site/?author=1&author_view=pinboard`

Yes, and that is because in that URL, the `author` value is a user ID.

But in the "pretty" version of that URL (e.g. `http://mylocalsite.site/author/admin/pinboard`), WordPress uses the user's "nice name" (from the `user_nicename` column in the `wp_users` table) which by default is the same as the username (from the `user_login` column in the users table).

Therefore, in your rewrite rule's query (the 2nd parameter for `add_rewrite_rule()`), you need to use `author_name` and **not** `author`:

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    $author_base . '/([^/]*)/([^/]*)',
    'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&author_view=$matches[2]', // use author_name
//  'index.php?author=$matches[1]&author_view=$matches[2]',      // and not "author"
    'top'
);
```

That way, [`is_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_author/) would return true on the page (with the `author_view` part in the URL) and thus, you'd not need to hook on `template_redirect` because the [author template like `author.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#author-display) would be loaded correctly for you.

So in summary, just correct the query argument's name and your rule would work without giving you those errors. :) (But be sure to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the permalink settings page)